# Is the set linear span of the family $\{ \sin nt\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ dense in the space $L^1(-\pi, \pi)$ ? True/False

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Is  the set  linear span of the  family $\{ \sin nt\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is dense in the  space  $L^1(-\pi, \pi)$ ? True/False

My try : Yes

i know that the  span of $\{ sin(nt)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}+\{ cos(nt)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is a dense subspace of $L^1$

so i think it will be  dense

Comment: No, but it is dense in the space of odd functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. $\int_{-1}^{1} \sin (nt)dt=0$ so any linear combination so these functions also has integral $0$. If $f$ is a limit in $L^{1}$ of such linear combinations then $\int_{-1}^{1} f(t) dt=0$.

In particular, the constant function $1$ cannot be approximated by linear combinations of $\{sin (nt): n\geq 1\}$.